# I can convert a string to an object in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert a String to an Object, something like this.

```
Dim ObjectName As String
Dim Object As Object

ObjectName = "Label1"

Set Object = ObjectName

Object.Caption = "Text"
```

This is something that would really help me a lot, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: An object can be a string without any fancy coding, but not all objects have a caption property, so your question does not really make any sense. Maybe instead, explain why you are trying to do this. Provide some context. Maybe you mean: `Dim Object1 As Label`? (using a variable name that is the same as a variable type can also cause problems, btw)

Comment: I have several names registered in the spreadsheet, and the Caption of my Labels has to be the same, but in order not to have to repeat the same code several times, I thought of creating a string that can be changed, to also change the object.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what labels are (userform labels?) you can [edit] your question and add more information and a screenshot if it helps

Comment: A simpler way to say it is this, I can convert a string, like "Label1", into an object, and use its Caption property afterwards:

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of the `.Tag` property? Every control would have one of those...

Comment: Sorry but I am Brazilian and it is really difficult to understand the comments. Sorry : (

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the labels defined in a sheet and change their caption?

Answer (score 0):

example from [ms docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addlabel). add label as shape

```
Sub test()
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddLabel(msoTextOrientationVertical, _
100, 100, 60, 150) _
.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test Label"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the labels as `ActiveX` objects on a sheet and set their `.Caption` property as follows

```
Public Sub SetLabelText()

    Dim i As Long, n As Long, Obj as Object
    n = Sheet1.OLEObjects().Count
    For i = 1 To n
        Set Obj = Sheet1.OLEObjects(i).Object
        Obj.Caption = "Text #" & CStr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

with the expected result

[image: scr]

You can also access a specific label, by name `OLEObjects("Label1").Object`